# Unresolved symbols in calendar application

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am following the code from [this tutorial](http://free-tutorials.org/android-calendar-application-example-part-1/) and I have two unresolved symbols in my java file.

The website's java file is called MainActivity.java, but mine is calendar.java. The code is as follows:

```
//imports
```

public class calendar extends ActionBarActivity
   {

```
CalendarView calendar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    //this can be added to make a calendar (?)
    calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    //inflate the menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    //handle action bar item clicks here
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_settings)
        return true;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

In the onCreateOptionsMenu method, the R.menu.main is an unresolved symbol. I'm not sure if maybe the tutorial is referring to something that I don't have in my application?

It's the same thing for the onOptionsItemSelected method. R.id.action_settings is unresolved.

I'm honestly not sure what these lines are supposed to be doing, much less why they aren't doing it. How do I fix it so that my calendar will work?

Comment: Do you have a class named `R` and is it imported?

Comment: I'm working in android studio. R is used to access the res file, which contains all the .xml files and .java files. I'm not sure what menu.main is supposed to be accessing, since I don't see a menu folder within the res folder. Nor do I see an id file.